# How does Cell Minute Tracker work?

Tags: php, screen-scraping, web-scraping

It's been a mystery how does Cell Minute Tracker manage to fetch AT&T users data.
Maybe someone here has the long waited answer.

I'm really curious rather they got a confirmation to scrape user’s cellular report
And how they can fire up multiple requests to AT&T site without being banned?

I'm waiting for someone who could shed some light on this mystery

Thanks

link: http://www.uquery.com/apps/311637771-cell-minute-tracker-for-att

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell the application is running locally on a iPhone, it is using the user created login account, so it is just like the user going to the site, thus no issues.

Internally it would be scraping the site to get the information to display to the user.

Now, given your question who knows if they got confirmation, but the second part of your question in regards to multiple requests is moot, since it is each device contacting, not their server.

Comment: They're doing it locally on their servers since they use push notifications service.

which means that they need to get the updated info in some interval and not to be depended on the users habits of use.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to know exactly how they're doing it, however my guess is they're requesting your balance and minute usage and just parsing the text message you receive back with that information.

```
// for at&t
*BAL# for balance on your account
*DATA# for data usage
```

The text message is free.

Answer (score 0):

How do they do it for Rogers in Canada?
Does Rogers provide a text message with the current SMS and minutes balance?